# Jbpm7 spring boot business application: No active transaction after arjuna transation timeout

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm, narayana

I'm encountering the same problem described here: https://issues.redhat.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/RHBPMS-4621.

I use Jbpm 7.41 business application with oracle database. Under high load, transaction timeouts are detected and arjuna marks them for rollback. Then, the Jbpm executor thread reuses the same transaction and throws a repetitive message "No active transaction...".

Does someone know how to fix this problem? I think that the same fix done for JtaTransactionManager in RHBPMS-4621 is needed for KieSpringTransactionManager.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

we checked your question within the Narayana team http://narayana.io and with guys from JBPM. We agree that's seems to be an issue within the `KieSpringTransactionManager`. The best would be to create a new issue in JBPM tracker - see it here: https://issues.redhat.com/projects/JBPM

With that the JBPM team should be announced about it and somebody will take care of it.

Thanks
Ondra

Comment: Thank you for your feedback,I opened an issue to JBPM (Business applications) here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBPM-9450

Answer (score 0):

I think you should switch off deployment synchronizer:

```
<property name="org.jbpm.deploy.sync.enabled" value="false"/>
```