# Explicitly joining a JTA transaction requires a JTA transaction issue with jBPM 7 and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm, kie-server, narayana

We use jBPM 7.41 business application with Oracle database. Under high load, transaction timeouts are detected and arjuna marks them for rollback. Then, jBPM executor thread reuse the same transaction and throws a repetitive exception "No active transaction...". The jBPM is working at the begining but after few minutes of work, there is no active JTA transaction. We use asynchronous executor with a simple command throwing exception, the processes execute normally but as soon as Arjuna Transaction Reaper cancels a transaction, the executor threads will throw the same exception "Explicitly joining a JTA transaction requires a JTA transaction".

We think that the same fix done for JtaTransactionManager in is needed for KieSpringTransactionManager.

We created a ticket here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBPM-9450 describing the problem and attached logs and a project to be able to reproduce it.

We tried several options, replacing Narayana with Atomikos and Bitronix, Oracle with PostgreSQL but the issue is the same.

It seems that we’re encountering the same problem described here: https://issues.redhat.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/RHBPMS-4621.

Thank you in advance,

We use:

- Spring Boot: 2.2.2.RELEASE
- Kie Server: 7.45.0.Final
- Narayana: 5.9.0.Final

Logs : https://issues.redhat.com/secure/attachment/12501068/logs.txt

Sample project to reproduce the issue available here: https://issues.redhat.com/secure/attachment/12501190/jbpm-perfs-oracle.zip

Comment: make sure that auto-commit is off

Comment: Could please provide more details, which place, which configuration file and property? Thank you.

Comment: the auto-commit mode of the database, in oracle it must be off by default, but check it may be it was on. get the value by command prompt using `show autocommit`

Comment: We tested this Sample project with PostgreSQL also and we still face the same issue of  "Explicitly joining a JTA transaction requires a JTA transaction", it seems that the issue is related to the jBPM (Executor) <-> Spring Boot.

Comment: Just i would mention there is possibility to create a JBPM issue if it's considered to be a trouble of the runtime (similar as pointed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591565/jbpm7-spring-boot-business-application-no-active-transaction-after-arjuna-trans)